# How can I show the x row of the y column?

Tags: php, sql

I selected 10 values of my datatable I want to display eatch one in a label form: This is my code:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_ou group by reference  order by sum(quantite) desc LIMIT 10;");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
echo $row1[5];
```

**the result:** Mandrin Mandrin Extracteur Mandrin Obturateur Mandrin Câbleadapt Câble adapt Mandrin Extracteur

**What I want:** label1: Mandrin

label2: Mandrin

label3: Extracteur

.......

Comment: So increment a counter variable inside your loop, and then echo `label` and the content of that counter variable first, and then the actual column value.

Comment: I would not use numeric indices but that's an opinion.. have you tried adding text/HTML to this? I would expect this to actually result in `MandrinMandrinExtracteurMandrin...`

Comment: please @CBroe can you give me an example of the increment counter.

Comment: I just need to know how to select specific rows in php: for example in column we use $row[x]

Comment: _"I just need to know how to select specific rows in php"_ - no, you don't. You want to output the data from _all_ selected records, and your while loop already iterates over them one by one. So there really is not need whatsoever to address any _specific_ row directly at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe said, you can add a counter that increments with each while loop.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_ou group by reference  order by sum(quantite) desc LIMIT 10;");
$i = 1; //This is the counter variable
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "Label ".$i.": ".$row1[5];
    $i++;
}
//Excpected Output for first loop:
//Label 1: Mandarin
```